# React - preserve identity of an element between parents

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

Is there any way in React to preserve the identity of an element when it moves between different parents?

For example:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {condition() ? (
        <Parent1><Child /></Parent1>
      ) : (
        <Parent2><Child /></Parent2>
      )}
    </div>
  );
});
```

In my case, **Child** contains a **video** element, and when the **condition()** changes mid-way through the video, it gets recreated, which causes hiccups in the playback. I would like it to continue playing smoothly.

I tried:

- Memoizing all of the components - didn't help
- Using a "key" prop - didn't help either, as the key only matters within the same parent
- Passing the Child to the parents as a "children" prop ... didn't help either

There is nothing strange going on in the parents, it can even be something like:

```
const Parent1OrParent2 = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <span>Hello I am parent 1 or parent 2</span>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
});
```

Is it even possible to preserve the element at all?

Comment: Maybe not the optimal solution, but you can render them both and hide the other one with css and disable its functionality with props

Comment: that is not possible at least in react you need to separate `Child` and manage it separately according to the conditions

Comment: I came up with the method see the answer below

Comment: What’s in Parent1 and Parent2?

Comment: @Adam I included a simple example of what could be in Parent1 and Parent2. It turns out it can be solved if they look exactly the same (see Tachibana Shin's answer below), but it still remains a question whether it can be solved if Parent1 and Parent2 are different.

Comment: @PetrSmital I was prompting a question more than providing an answer. Do you actually need a different parent? Can you use the same parent component, but provide some props that cause it to render in a different way under certain desired circumstances? React is built upon the fact that a different parent, means children will be remounted, which 99.99% of the time is fine. Look to see if you can achieve what you want by using the same parent, instead of trying to fight against the framework

Comment: See simple remounting example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-c4ya61?file=src%2FApp.js The react team is extremely astute at knowing what's actually needed vs giving devs footguns. There's a good reason why react doesn't have "global" keys (unlike something like Flutter) which allows you to re-use children with different parents. It's needless complexity.

Comment: For example, if your single `Parent` always rendered the same child (the component you want to maintain) but took props to replace the text, or the span, or some other dynamic content that is currently hardcoded inside Parent1/Parent2 - then you'd be fine. **Strongly** recommend you rewrite your parents this way, instead of trying to hack it

Comment: @Adam sure, that would absolutely be the best approach if possible. But it's not always possible. Say, for example, you have a table and want the child to jump between different rows/columns without being recreated. You can't just keep the child in one place in the DOM and recreate the whole rest of the table with graphics or absolutely positioned elements something, that would be crazy.

Comment: @PetrSmital I don't think you're thinking in react enough here. What you're saying would be crazy, yet has also somehow managed to build thousands upon thousands of react applications, some of them extremely high performance and battled tested (like Facebook). There's an RFC for what you think you want, but, again, in practice, this has not been necessary for React devs to have to build their applications. I highly doubt you've come across the very instance where it's absolutely necessary. Please check this out: https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/pull/34#issuecomment-901466409

Answer (score -1):

the only way to do that is to pre-initialize children so that it is a:

```js
const MyComponent = () => {
  const child = <Child />

  return (
    <div>
      {condition() ? (
        <Parent1>{child}</Parent1>
      ) : (
        <Parent2>{child}</Parent2>
      )}
    </div>
  );
});
```

Demo: https://playcode.io/1190983

Comment: Thank you. This is actually really interesting. It works, but only as long as Parent1 and Parent2 consist of the exact same DOM elements. If you make Parent1 a <div> and Parent2 a <span> or <p> or <> or anything, or even just enclose the child in one extra <div> in one of them, it stops working.

Comment: i think the fastest solution is to wrap both parent1 and parent2 in `<></>`

Comment: I did that, but it even matters what is inside. If you make it `<><div>{child}</div></>` vs.  `<><div><div>{child}</div></div></>`, it already doesn't work. My actual use case is that there are several video elements on the page (one per child), and they can be arranged on the page in different grid layouts (the different parents), which can, in general, consist of totally different DOM elements. And I want to be able to change the layout, i.e. insert the same children into different parents, while the videos inside the children keep playing without interruptions.

Comment: you can try wrapping `<Child>` into `<KeepAlive>` of `react-activation` package i think it will work

Comment: I don't understand how this playcode demonstrates anything. The state is reset - i.e. the child is remounted - every time you toggle the parent. This is wrong.

Comment: @Adam Why do you think it's wrong? it works and we are looking for a way to make it work with different dom structures

Comment: @TachibanaShin - it does indeed work, not sure what playcode I was looking at earlier. It's still poor practice, not idiomatic react, and works in only very slim cases.

Comment: As you'll see, semantically, there's no difference between declaring it first with `const`, or just declaring it inline - nothing gets "preinitialized" - https://playcode.io/1191927. If you use a slightly more convoluted example (https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-c4ya61?file=src%2FApp.js) that uses actually different parents other than fragments, it doesn't work

Comment: so i say need to use `<KeepAlive>` or even more intensive case do real DOM rendering

Comment: there is `<keep-alive>` in vue but it seems react needs an external plugin to do that